# Fitting background image to screen and positioning it to bottom

Tags: css, background-image

I want to apply a background image to my web page so that it covers the whole page. But the image height is bigger than the page height and I want the bottom of the image to align with the bottom of the page. Is it possible? Here's the technique I'm using so far, which doesn't make this bottom alignment:

```
background-image:url(background.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
```

I tried to add `center bottom` after url() but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `background-position` to accomplish what you want.
How to use it: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Comment: Works, thanks ! Jonen: can I set a difference (say 50px) at the bottom of the page, so that background image start covering the screen not from its actual bottom (the image) but from 50px above its bottom? Not sure if I'm clear. It's like: background-position: center bottom+50px

Comment: Yes, just remove the px from your attribute so it will be like `background-position:center bottom+50;`

Comment: Got it, it was: bottom 50px